# Calculate $I(\alpha, x,y)=\int\limits_0^1 {{v^{\alpha  - 1}}{{(1 - vx)}^{\alpha  - 1}}{e^{vy}}dv,\,\,\,0 < \alpha ,x,y < 1}.$

Tags: integration, special-functions, definite-integrals

I want to calculate this integral with singularity:

$$I(\alpha, x,y)=\int\limits_0^1 {{v^{\alpha  - 1}}{{(1 - vx)}^{\alpha  - 1}}{e^{vy}}dv,\,\,\,0 < \alpha ,x,y < 1}. $$

I hope to obtain a closed formula via special functions, maybe some hypergeometric functions. A related differential equation for solving $I(\alpha, x,y)$ as a function of $x$,$y$ is also interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand in series with respect to $y$ and integrate term-wise:
$$
   I(\alpha, x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{y^n}{n!} \int_0^1 v^{n+\alpha-1} (1-x v)^{\alpha-1} \mathrm{d} v = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{y^n}{n!} \frac{1}{n+\alpha} {}_2 F_1\left(n+\alpha, 1-\alpha; n+\alpha+1 ;x\right)
$$
From here you see that this is confluent bivariate hypergeometric function, [Horn function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornFunction.html) $\Phi_1$:
$$
   I(\alpha, x, y) = \frac{1}{\alpha} \Phi_1\left(\alpha, 1-\alpha, \alpha+1, x, y\right)
$$